# Problems after migrating to Entity Framework 5

Tags: entity-framework-5

We just moved all of our entities into a new solution so that we could start developing EF5/MVC4/net4.5. However, I have an issue that is really baffling me and I have searched relentlessly for a possible cause, but have found nothing.

Using Code-First, migrations were created, database tables were populated with no issue.

The Problem is that no matter what entity I attempt to query against, I get the following error:
System.Data.EntityCommandCompilationException
**{"The given key was not present in the dictionary."}**

Here is the StackTrack:

```
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)
   at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.Structures.MemberDomainMap.GetDomainInternal(MemberPath path)
   at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.QueryRewriting.FragmentQueryKB.CreateIsOfTypeCondition(MemberPath currentPath, IEnumerable`1 derivedTypes, MemberDomainMap domainMap)
   at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.QueryRewriting.FragmentQueryKB.CreateVariableConstraintsRecursion(EdmType edmType, MemberPath currentPath, MemberDomainMap domainMap, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.QueryRewriting.FragmentQueryKB.CreateVariableConstraintsRecursion(EdmType edmType, MemberPath currentPath, MemberDomainMap domainMap, EdmItemCollection edmItemCollection)
   at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewgenContext..ctor(ViewTarget viewTarget, EntitySetBase extent, IEnumerable`1 extentCells, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, ConfigViewGenerator config, MemberDomainMap queryDomainMap, MemberDomainMap updateDomainMap, StorageEntityContainerMapping entityContainerMapping)
   at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.CreateViewgenContext(EntitySetBase extent, ViewTarget viewTarget, CqlIdentifiers identifiers)
   at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateQueryViewForExtentAndType(StorageEntityContainerMapping entityContainerMapping, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, KeyToListMap`2 views, EntitySetBase entity, EntityTypeBase type, ViewGenMode mode)
   at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewGenerator.GenerateQueryViewForSingleExtent(KeyToListMap`2 views, CqlIdentifiers identifiers, EntitySetBase entity, EntityTypeBase type, ViewGenMode mode)
   at System.Data.Mapping.ViewGeneration.ViewgenGatekeeper.GenerateTypeSpecificQueryView(StorageEntityContainerMapping containerMapping, ConfigViewGenerator config, EntitySetBase entity, EntityTypeBase type, Boolean includeSubtypes, Boolean& success)
   at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.TryGenerateQueryViewOfType(EntityContainer entityContainer, EntitySetBase entity, EntityTypeBase type, Boolean includeSubtypes, GeneratedView& generatedView)
   at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.SerializedGeneratedViewOfType(Pair`2 arg)
   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.<>c__DisplayClass2.<Evaluate>b__0()
   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
   at System.Data.Mapping.StorageMappingItemCollection.ViewDictionary.TryGetGeneratedViewOfType(MetadataWorkspace workspace, EntitySetBase entity, EntityTypeBase type, Boolean includeSubtypes, GeneratedView& generatedView)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.TryGetGeneratedViewOfType(EntitySetBase extent, EntityTypeBase type, Boolean includeSubtypes, GeneratedView& generatedView)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ExpandView(Node node, ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.ProcessScanTable(Node scanTableNode, ScanTableOp scanTableOp, IsOfOp& typeFilter)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(FilterOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.FilterOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitRelOpDefault(RelOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Visit(ProjectOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.ProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.SubqueryTrackingVisitor.VisitChildren(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitDefault(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfNode.VisitPhysicalOpDefault(PhysicalOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.Visit(PhysicalProjectOp op, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.PhysicalProjectOp.Accept[TResultType](BasicOpVisitorOfT`1 v, Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.InternalTrees.BasicOpVisitorOfT`1.VisitNode(Node n)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PreProcessor.Process(PlanCompiler planCompilerState, StructuredTypeInfo& typeInfo, Dictionary`2& tvfResultKeys)
   at System.Data.Query.PlanCompiler.PlanCompiler.Compile(List`1& providerCommands, ColumnMap& resultColumnMap, Int32& columnCount, Set`1& entitySets)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityCommandDefinition..ctor(DbProviderFactory storeProviderFactory, DbCommandTree commandTree)
```

At first I thought that is could be our new implementation of enums or other complex types, but since even the simplest entity with no relationships throws the same error, I am at a loss. Thanks in advance for any input.

Comment: Do you have any hierarchy/inheritance? Do you map anything conditionally? There is something in your model that triggers this condition. It does not matter whether you try an entity with or without relation ships since this happens for the model in general and not for the entity you are trying to use. Try remove some (half?) entities from your model (e.g. in OnModelCreating) to isolate what is causing the problem. Once you have a contained repro you can file a bug on http://entityframework.codeplex.com